# Furnace transformer hot to the touch

Tags: transformer

Should the transformer be hot when the furnace isnt running? replaced the transformer and it is hot to the touch but not hot enough to burn fingers..

Comment: Transformers can take quite a lot of heat. [100°C would not be a **too** high temperature for a modern transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulation_system#Temperature_classes), and you would probably not keep your fingers on that...

Comment: Temps over 90c start to break down the insulation I don’t know many that could maintain contact with 100c that is 212f .

Answer (score 1):

What is the size of the transformer? Usually excessive heat in a transformer means it is undersized. Larger transformers actually have there temp increase listed on them. If you get one the same voltage but a larger kw / kva output it will not run as warm if you are concerned.

Comment: Heat is good..lol

Answer (score 1):

Yes, transformer primaries use electricity (and therefore get warm) even when there is no load on the secondary winding. It's usually just 5-10 watts, and that'll be hot to the touch depending on how much thermal mass it has and airflow around it.

It's normal for the typical cheap 24VAC 40VA transformers used in security systems and security camera get hot enough to discolor their plastic shells, so I'd say it's normal for a similar furnace transformer without a plastic shell will get just as hot even though I've never actually touched or measured mine on my furnace.

I've heard of people using 24VAC  switching power supplies instead of 24VAC transformers in their furnaces to save wasted energy. That constant 5-10 watt draw can cost you $5-10 a year in electricity. The down side is that they're more likely to fail vs a transformer, which is not something you usually want to risk on a furnace. Also the power from one is "noisy" and might not play well with a furnace controller that wasn't expecting it.

Comment: Do you mean 24VDC switching supplies instead?

Comment: A 10w draw at 11.5 cents per kWh is only ~ 1 dollar a year. 5-10$ is crazy high.

Comment: @3Phase - a transformer will put out AC, so since that what the original system expects... I'd stick with that.

Comment: @EdBeal Double check your math. 10 watts for a year at 11.5 cents is $10.08/year. An easy rule of thumb for 24/7 usage is watts equals the yearly cost.

Comment: Actually I got that from a power company calculator, that’s the rate it put in I just put the wattage and length of time. Think about it a 100w lightbulb would cost 10$ per month at your number. I have 10 incandescent hard service bulbs on from dusk to dawn in my horse stalls, my home is all electric my total bill is around 150 most months just the lights in the stalls would cost close to 100 a month then the 12 floods in the riding arena that are usually on at least 3-4 hours a day and 4 other dusk to dawn barn lights 1 at each entrance to the arena. That doesn’t even get to the house.

Comment: @EdBeal Maybe you can find the error in my math then? I don't know what I'm doing wrong: 100 watts equals 0.1 kilowatt hours. 0.1 kWh times 24 hours equals 2.4 kW per day. 2.4 kW per day times 365 days in a year equals 876 kW per year. 876 kW per year times $0.115 per kW equals $96.36 per year.

Comment: Number 1 is lamps are not based on 24 hour burn time most are 4 hours and even commercial sites only use 9 for energy usage calculations

Comment: Note I just went on another site that allowed me to change the values. 24 hours per day, 10w @ .115 (11.5 cents) cost per year $10.8 energyusecalculator.com

Comment: @DaveM -- the issue is that switching supplies generally *never* have AC outputs (otherwise, we'd call them inverters ;P)